# Why is the tap operator impacting stream flow?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

For some reason having a tap operator is altering the output of a stream (actually providing my expected result). When I remove the tap the subsequent filter no longer appears to work.

I have run the code below on codesandbox with the

```
  tap(([prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent]) =>
    console.log(directionChange(prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent))
  ),
```

included as well as commented out.  Without the tap the subsequent filter doesn't appear to work and I get a constant stream of paired mouse events.

```
// Returns true if the predominant movement in the mouse has changed direction
  const directionChange = (prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent) => {
     const dominantAxisMovement =
       Math.abs(currentMouseEvent.movementX) >
       Math.abs(currentMouseEvent.movementY) ? "X" : "Y";

     if (dominantAxisMovement === "X") {
       return (
         Math.sign(currentMouseEvent.movementX) !==
         Math.sign(prevMouseEvent.movementX)
       );
     } else {
       return (
         Math.sign(currentMouseEvent.movementY) !==
         Math.sign(prevMouseEvent.movementY)
       );
    }
};

const mouseDirectionSwitch$ = fromEvent(document, "mousemove").pipe(
  pairwise(),
  tap(([prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent]) =>
    console.log(directionChange(prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent))
  ),
  filter(([prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent]) =>
    directionChange(prevMouseEvent, currentMouseEvent)
  )
);

mouseDirectionSwitch$.subscribe(passed => console.log(passed));
```

What I am trying to achieve is an observable that only emits when the user changes the direction of a mouse movement (and by change movement I mean up to down and left to right, not subtle changes). With the tap it works but can anyone explain why the tap operator is required here to get the desired output?  I thought the tap operator returned an identical observable and would therefore have no effect on the output of the stream it is in.

Comment: Is this a vanilla JavaScript environment? This seems quite odd; my only guess is that maybe the event objects are getting reused, like React uses an event pool. Also, if you have this running in a code sandbox, can you post a link? I really don't see any issues with your code.

Comment: Maybe the log statements are just slowing things down enough so that the move events are more dramatic?  If you’re moving up and to the left for example and events are cycling very quickly you might get “up one” then “left one” as separate events and that would trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. Jacob - your suggestion made me go and recreate this in its own independent project... and it worked fine. So I shut everything down and reopened the original project and low and behold it worked. I'm really not sure why it wasn't working before (despite full page refreshes to flush any remnant event handlers) but the age old "have you tried restarting your computer" was all I really needed. Thanks for your ideas!